# Filter output of script to a file, an the full output to another file

Tags: linux, shell, grep, stdout

I have a script that get logs from an api every 30 minutes, I want to filter the output of the script an store the filtered data to a file, and also store the full data to another file.
I have tried this, but I get an empty file

```
script.py | tee >> ( grep 'MAAS' > filtered_$date.log  ) fulldata_$date.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```sh
script.py | tee "fulldata_$date.log" | grep 'MAAS' > "filtered_$date.log"
```

First `tee` the unfiltered data, and `grep` still gets to see everything and filters it down.

You could invert it with process substitution, something like

```sh
script.py | tee >(grep 'MAAS' > "filtered_$date.log") > "fulldata_$date.log"
```

but that feels neither simpler nor easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I think the second one works for me, because the files have to keep getting data (append) until the day ends.... | tee >(grep 'MAAS' >> "filtered_$date.log") >> "fulldata_$date.log"

Comment: @Mefistofeles To append, you could use `script.py | tee -a "fulldata_$date.log" | grep 'MAAS' >> "filtered_$date.log"`